# Not enough values to unpack in chained assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration, iterable-unpacking

I know this isn't the way to assign multiple values in one line, but I'm just trying to understand what the 4th line is doing here:

```
a = input("blah blah")
b = input("blah blah blah")
c = input("blaaah")
A=a,B=b,C=c
print(A,B,C)
```

If `a`,`b`,`c` were `int` or `float` types, it would show an `"int/float object is not iterable"` error.

If `a`,`b`,`c` are strings and say `a="ab"`,`b="cd"`,`c="ef"`, the print will show:

```
ef f f
```

If the strings are of a length `!= 2`, it shows a `"not enough/too many values to unpack"` error.

Can someone explain what's happening?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the disassembly to see what exactly is going on:

```
from dis import dis
dis('A=a,B=b,C=c')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (c)
              2 DUP_TOP
              4 STORE_NAME               1 (A)
              6 DUP_TOP
              8 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
             10 STORE_NAME               2 (a)
             12 STORE_NAME               3 (B)
             14 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
             16 STORE_NAME               4 (b)
             18 STORE_NAME               5 (C)
             20 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             22 RETURN_VALUE
```

What this is saying is that the chained assignment:

```
A=a,B=b,C=c
```

is *actually* evaluated as:

```
A = c
a, B = c 
b, C = c
```

This is why if you print the value of `a` and `b` you'll see they'll also be equal to `'e'`.

This is also why, if `c` (`a` and `b` play no role here) is a string with a length `> 2` the unpackings will fail.

Comment: That is not correct that `a` and `b` have no role there. If you try out `A = 4, B = "aa"` you will get `SyntaxError: can't assign to literal` and if you try to get `A`'s value you will get `NameError: name 'A' is not defined`

Comment: @nutmeg64 Let's go over this again. What happens is `A = 'aa'` is attempted and then an attempt to perform `4, B = 'aa'` is made. The whole thing fails because since this is performed in a single step the `SyntaxError` prevents the whole assignment, `A` is not assigned to and you get the `NameError`. Try `a = 1; b =3; A = a,b = 'ef'` and see the output.

Comment: That is correct. Hence your code snippet below "is actually evaluated as:" is incorrect. You imply there that the assignment `A = c` happens __before__ any other assignments.

Comment: @nutmeg64 `A = c` happens before any other assignments, I'm not implying that, I'm openly stating it. You can see that in the bytecode, you can also see it [by example](https://ideone.com/dAkzsn). In the previous example, the `SyntaxError` just prevented the whole thing from running, it wasn't a good example to illustrate your point about evaluation which happens at *run-time*.

Answer (score 1):

**CLARIFICATION:** 
My answer does not explain "How Python interpreter works". The described series of events depicted in my answer a mere simplification of the situation to help beginner programmers understand it better.

What is happening here is this:

```
A = (a, B) = (b, C) = c
```

That is how the interpreter sees it.

This is a multiple assignment statement.

The interpreter tries to unpack `c` as an iterable of two arguments.
Then tries to assign the first argument to `b` and the second argument to `C`.

In the next step there is a simple <strike>tuple to tuple</strike> two argument assignment where `(b, C)` is unpacked and assigned as `a = b` and `B = C`.

In the final step, that <strike>tuple</strike> iterable which contains two arguments needs to be unpacked and assigned to `A`. since `A` is a new variable here, the tuple won't unpack and just assign the <strike>tuple</strike> iterable to `A`.

For example:

```
>>> c = (1, 'one')
>>> A = a, B = b, C = c
>>> A
(1, 'one')
>>> B
'one'
>>> C
'one'
>>> a
1
>>> b
1
>>> c
(1, 'one')
```

Comment: Um, no. This isn't what happens, I've added the disassembly in my answer which shows what the interpreter is *actually* doing. If your claim was correct, `A` would equal `('e', 'f')` if `c` was `'ef'` and *not* `'ef'`.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard edited. Don't get hung up on the small things ;)

Comment: Again, this is incorrect. There's a very clear set of steps that is taken in multiple assignments and you are misrepresenting it.

Comment: I am not mistaken since `UNPACK_SEQUENCE` is exactly what it means: unpacking an iterable (since iterable is a sequence). If you are suggesting that I'm mistaken as to the __order of events__ I described then I merely did that as a way to simplify the explanation of the results. Of course that is not __exactly__ the way the interpreter does things. I do not presume to know _everything_ about the interpreter and it's backend operations.

Comment: And further explanation on that subject (how Python interpreter works) I think will only confuse beginner programmers. That is why I did not agree with you answer and didn't gave it an upvote, since the asker of this question is obviously a beginner.

Comment: Again, this is incorrect not only because the order of operations is wrong but also because you imply that the assignment `A = a, b` is made. `A` is assigned to `c`  directly, there's *no* unpacking going on there.

Comment: What you are saying exactly qualifies as "order of events". If you read again and look at the example, `A` receives the value of `c`.